# Why is my tag pointing to a different commit locally and remotely?

Tags: git, git-tag

I tagged a commit and `git push`ed it to `origin`. Then my colleague moved the tag to a commit he made and pushed. I pulled `origin`, but when I `git log` I still see the tag pointing to my commit. When I go to the web interface I can see that the tag points to my colleague's newer commit. I tried `git fetch --all` and `git fetch --tags`, to no avail.
Why is my local tag not reflecting the change on `origin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags are not expected to move, so by default git fetch is refusing to move the tag.  (The output of `git fetch` should tell you that it rejected the tag update, with a note like "would clobber existing tag".)

You can force the local tag to update with

```
git fetch -f --tags
```

In general, you should avoid a process in which you routinely move tags.